# expected string or bytes-like object Python

Tags: python, string, k-means

[image]

```
### Numerical data for the algorithm, NP_xx/XP_xx are protein identifiers 
#from RefSeq database
processed_numerical = processed.loc[:,[x for x in processed.columns if bool (re.search("NP_|XP_",x)) == True]]
```

I keep getting the 'expected string or bytes-like object' error, and I don't know why. Can someone please explain to me what happened to this code?

Comment: what does `print(processed.columns)` shows ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that your are using pandas to preprocess dataset
processed.columns[i] not a string or byte-like, so you should check this k
maybe you should set the columns name and set the row number like `processed.columns["col"][row_num]`

```
k for k in processed.columns
processed.loc[:,[k for k in processed.columns if bool (re.search("NP_|XP_", k)) == True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for `re.search` is `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`, so it takes two strings and a boolean. Since "NP_|XP_" is definitely a string, and the last value is optional, then it seems like `x` is not a string, so it's complaining. I'm not sure what that data is, but perhaps you can cast it to a string like this:

`x for x in processed.columns if bool (re.search("NP_|XP_",str(x)))`